# CryptoJS creates the same hash value for different files

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am using CryptoJS to create a hash value of the upload file. However, all files that I upload produce the same hash value. I know that the issue is inside my "onFileChange" call, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../CSS/FileSelectorCSS.css';
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

class FileSelectorComponent extends Component {

    state = {

        // Initially, no file is selected 
        selectedFile: null
    };

    // On file select (from the pop up) 
    onFileChange = event => {
        var text = '';
        // Update the state 
        this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            text = (reader.result);
        }

        reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);

        var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(text));

        console.log(hash.toString());
    };

    // File content to be displayed after 
    // file upload is complete 
    fileData = () => {

        if (this.state.selectedFile) {

            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>File Details:</h2>
                    <p>File Name: {this.state.selectedFile.name}</p>
                    <p>File Type: {this.state.selectedFile.type}</p>
                    <p>
                        Last Modified:{" "}
                        {this.state.selectedFile.lastModifiedDate.toDateString()}
                    </p>
                </div>
            );
        } 
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                </div>
                {this.fileData()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

export default connect()(FileSelectorComponent);

[image]

Expected value:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating your hash before the reader gets loaded.

The hash "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" is the MD5 hash of an empty string.

There lines :

```
reader.onloadend = function () {
  text = (reader.result);
}
```

mean that the `text` variable will be assigned the result when the reader finished loading, *asynchronously*. But by that time, the rest of the function has already been executed.

So you need to make sure that the process takes place after the `text` variable gets its new value, like this :

```
reader.onloadend = function () {
  text = (reader.result);

  reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
  var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(text));
  console.log(hash.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // On file select (from the pop up) 
onFileChange = event => {
    var text = '';
    // Update the state 
    this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
        text = (reader.result);
        var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(text));
        console.log(hash.toString());
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);

    //console.log(text);
   

    //console.log(hash.toString());
};
```

CryptoJS needs to be placed inside the callback function. It fixed my issue.